# Upgrading from CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I've written my first iOS app, Amaziograph, which uses Core Graphics. 
My app is a drawing app and it employs drawing a lot of lines (Up to 30 lines one by one, at different locations + some shadow to simulate brush blur, and it needs to appear as if all lines are drawn at the same time) with CG, which I find to be slow. In fact, when I switch to Retina and try drawing just a single line with my finger, I need to wait a second or so before it is drawn.

I realised that Core Graphics no longer meets my app's requirements as I'd like to make it use the Retina display's advantages and add some photoshop-style brushes.

My question is, is there a graphics library more faster and powerful than Core Graphics, but with simple interface. All I need is drawing simple lines with size, opacity, softness and possibly with some more advanced brushes. I'm thinking of OpenGL after I saw Apple's GLPaint app, but it seems a bit complicated for me with all those framebuffers, contexts and so on. I am looking for something that has similar to CG's ideology, so it wouldn't take much time rewriting my code.  Also, right now I'm doing all my drawing in UIImage views, so it would be nice to draw on top of UIImages directly.

Here is an extract of the code I'm using to draw right now:

```
//...Begin image contest >> draw the previous image in >> set stroke style >>
CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y-offset);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y-offset);
CGContextStrokePath(currentContext);
//Send to an UIImage and end image contest...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not going to find another graphics library with better performance than Core Graphics for the iOS platforms. Most likely your application can be significantly optimised, there are many tricks to use. You might be interested in the WWDC video 506 from 2012:

http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/
￼
Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance

They demonstrate a paint application using Core Graphics that works at full frame rate.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of optimising my code any further. This will definitely help me make my app faster.